# non-www to www redirection except one url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I can redirect all requests from https://example.com to https://www.example.com with these two lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But if request is like https://example.com/api/v1/xyz, I don't want to redirect it. It shouldn't be https://www.example.com/api/v1/xyz

I couldn't find any example on this one so I'm asking you guys. I'm not good at apache configurations.

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/api/v1/XYZ  [NC]` with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]`and test.

Comment: Didn't worked, I have some extra parameters in my request like: https://example.com/api/v1/1/get-availabilities?xyz, https://example.com/api/v1/1/reserve etc. So if request has /api/v1/ I need to not redirect it.

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/api/v1/.*$  [NC]` and test.